# Number of equivalence relation on $A=\{1,2,...,11\}$ such that $|A\setminus R| = 2$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

I am still trying to understand the question, I know that if a relation is reflexive (and equivalence relation is surely reflexive), then for every $a\in A$ , $(a,a)\in R$. But that means every equivalence relation on $A$ has atleast $11$ elements, which makes $|A \setminus R=0|$, because the cardinality of $R$ is surely $11$ or more. 
The final answer was $2^{10}-1$, so seems like I have some big misunderstanding that I don't understand where it comes from, I would really appreciate any explanation. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The fact that $(a,a)\in R$ does not mean than there are $11$ equivalence classes.  We could, for instance, have the trivial equivalence relation in which every element is equivalent to every other element.  That one only has $1$ equivalence class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $A/R$ represents the set of equivalence classes (with respect to $R$). So, the question is: how many equivalence relations can you define on $A$ such that there are exactly two equivalence classes? And the answer is: it's half the number of subsets $B$ of $A$ such that neither $B$ nor $A\setminus B$ is empty, because, for any such set $B$, you can define the equivalence relation$$a_1\mathrel Ra_2\iff a_1,a_2\in B\text{ or }a_1,a_2\notin B$$and the equivalence classes of $R$ and $B$ and $A\setminus B$; besides, $B$ and $A\setminus B$ induce the same equivalence relation. There are $2^{11}-2$ such sets, and therefore the answer is $2^{10}-1$.

Comment: Don't you need to divide by $2$ to account for symmetry?

Comment: @marlasca23 I missed that. It seems to be correct now.

Comment: Thank you, this clears my doubts about the question, but I didn't quite get the idea of the subsets, I have basic understanding of equivalence classes partitioning $A$, so we're searching for relations with $2$ equivalence classes which means we need to have exactly $2$ unempty equivalence classes. but I'm struggling with linking them with subsets $B$ that you mentioned, and couldn't understand the calculations after it.

Comment: I suggest that you check that the relation $R$ that I defined is indeed an equivalence relation and that the equivalence classes are $B$ and $A\setminus B$. Clearly, if I define $R$ starting from $A\setminus B$ instead of $B$, then I will get the same equivalence relation and therefore the same equivalence classes. On the other and, if $C\subset A$, if neither $C$ nor $A\setminus C$ is empty, if $C\ne B$, and if $C\ne A\setminus B$, then the equivalence relation that I get from $C$ is different from the one that I get from $B$, since the equivalence classes are distinct.

Comment: So, what remains to be done is to count the number of subsets $B$ of $A$ such that neither $B$ nor $A\setminus B$ are empty. The set $A$ has $2^{11}$ subsets, but neither $\emptyset$ nor $A$ matter here. So, there are $2^{11}-2$ possibilitites for $B$. And since the only other subset of $A$, other than $B$, that induces the same equivalence relation as $B$ is $A\setminus B$, the answer is$$\frac{2^{11}-2}2=2^{10}-1.$$

Comment: Honestly thanks alot, took me alot to grasp the idea, but I now get it better, I got a last question, about starting R from $A\setminus B$, why would we get the same equivalence classes? wouldn't we get the opposite equivalence classes from starting at $B$? or this is exactly the idea, like let $A=\{ 1,2,3,4 \}$, if we start at $A\setminus B=\{ 1\}$, we get $R= \{ (1,1) \}$ on $B$ and $ R={(2,2),(3,3),... } $ on $A\setminus B$, and that's one partition: $ \{ \{ 1 \},\{2,3,4\}\}$. then we keep counting until we reach  $\{ \{1,2,3\},\{4\}\}$. Thanks alot for everything.

Comment: I made a mistake in the definition of $R$. What I had there was not an equivalence relation. Sorry about that. Please check the edited version.

Comment: Thanks alot this clears everything, appreciate the help and explanations!